# Wrong regex matching

Tags: javascript, regex, match

When using the following regex

`([^\s]+)(\s+([^\s]+))*`

to match strings like this one

`\cmd 1 2`

the object returned from the match contains

```
0: \cmd 1 2
1: \cmd
2:  2
3: 2
```

I noticed that when a match is contained inside round brackets it will be added a new element in the returning object but why the third element is matching  `2` instead of  `1`?

Comment: Because this is capture group 3 `([^\s]+)` nested in group 2, see https://regex101.com/r/uVGZOc/1

Comment: Capture groups always hold the last match, as FB indicates above. If you wouldn't mind posting your full specification (input string, expected match/output, a counterexample if appropriate), we can probably provide a different way to get your result.

Comment: You can use `(?:)` for a "non-capturing group". This will logically group together the values you want, but it won't store it in a capture variable. This is one of the tricky "gotchas" with regexes that you learn over time :)

Comment: How to capture `1` and `2` in two separate groups using the `*` quantifier?

Comment: You cannot. You need to foresee for each potential argument a separate capture group, like `(\S+)(?:\s+(\S+))?(?:\s+(\S+))?` (note that `\S` is short for `[^\s]`). [See on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lUHDNO/1)